# Upload File using Vue 3 using axios & FormData causes page to reload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

Is there any other way to upload file using axios to laravel backend.
using Vite + Laravel 10 + Vue
code:

```
  let fdata = new FormData()
  fdata.append('file',file.value)
  axios.post('import', fdata)
```

cause the page to reload after submit. Is there any way to stop the reload by changing Vite config or something

I have tried using

```
   axios.post('import', {file: file.value})
```

but it the file parameter is passed as empty object -> file: {}

thanks

```
 <form
    @submit.prevent="onSubmit(e)"
  >
    <input
      type="file"
      :loading="loading"
      color="primary"
      @change="fileUpload($event)" 
      label="File input"
      />
      <Button
        class="me-3"
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
      <Button
        color="secondary"
        variant="tonal"
      >
        Cancel
      </Button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: is there another event act on this? event.stopPropagation() ? . if you can post a full code

Comment: full code posted